# When passing an argument with AddEventListener() can't get requestAnimationFrame to work properly

Tags: javascript

Im trying to get an animation on mouseenter and stop animation on mouseleave, but I'm onlny getting one cycle instead of a full cycle on mouseenter. Must be doing something wrong.

https://jsfiddle.net/b6kezaku/7/ here is a fragment.

```
var arrowUpFirst = document.getElementsByClassName('turn_up_svg')[0]
var arrowUpTransform = window.getComputedStyle(arrowUpFirst, null).getPropertyValue('transform')
var arrowUpTransformScale = arrowUpTransform.split(',')
var arrowUpValue = typeof arrowUpTransformScale[2] === 'string'
console.log(arrowUpValue)

var arrowNumberUpValue = Number(arrowUpValue) * 100
console.log(typeof arrowNumberUpValue === 'number')
var a = 'start'
var c = 'stop'
var fullCycle = 100

function up_svg(b) {
  if (a == b) {
    requestAnimationFrame(up_svg)
  }
  if (c == b) {
    cancelAnimationFrame(up_svg)
  }

  if (arrowNumberUpValue <= 100 && arrowNumberUpValue >= 50) {
    fullCycle--
    fullCycle <= 75 ? arrowNumberUpValue++ : arrowNumberUpValue--
      //document.querySelectorAll('p')[1].textContent = arrowNumberUpValue
      var trans = "scale(" + (arrowNumberUpValue / 100).toPrecision(2) + ") rotate(-90deg)"
    //document.querySelectorAll('p')[3].textContent = (arrowNumberUpValue/100).toPrecision(2)
    arrowUpFirst.style.transform = trans
    if (fullCycle < 52) {
      fullCycle = 100
      arrowNumberUpValue = 100
      //document.querySelectorAll('p')[2].textContent = arrowNumberUpValue  
    }
  }
}


//FirstFace.onmouseenter = up_svg
FirstFace.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  up_svg('start')
}, false)
//FirstFace.addEventListener('mouseenter', up_svg,false)
//FirstFace.addEventListener('mouseleave', up_svg.bind(null,'stop'),false)
FirstFace.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  up_svg('stop')
}, false)
```

Comment: Kaddath your right, here is an update with the missing variable https://jsfiddle.net/b6kezaku/9/

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is that when `requestAnimationFrame` invokes `up_svg`, it doesn't pass a value for `b`, so you don't trigger a second `requestAnimationFrame`.

Consider doing the following:

```
function loopAnimation() {
    requestAnimationFame(loop)
    // run animation
}

function startAnimation() {
    // cancel to prevent duplication
    cancelAnimationFrame(loopAnimation)
    requestAnimationFame(loopAnimation)
}

function stopAnimation() {
    cancelAnimationFrame(loopAnimation)
}
FirstFace.addEventListener('mouseenter', startAnimation,false)
FirstFace.addEventListener('mouseexit', stopAnimation,false)
```

In this case, `up_svg` gets split into three functions. One is dedicated to carrying out the animation and preserving it, while the other two can start or stop the loop.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when `requestAnimationFrame(up_svg);` runs the callback, it is passed a numerical value, so because `b` is neither 'start' or 'stop', it doesn't refresh again or ask again to `requestAnimationFrame(up_svg);`. Here is a little fix so that the function launches itself again:

in declarations:

```
var running = false;
```

in the function:

```
  if(a == b){
    running = true;
    cancelAnimationFrame(up_svg); //just a precaution
  }
  if(c == b){
    running = false;
    cancelAnimationFrame(up_svg)
  }else{
    if(running){
      requestAnimationFrame(up_svg);
    }
  }
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b6kezaku/10/